# SQL Server 2008 xpath on node array

Tags: arrays, sql-server, xpath

I am trying to run a query against some xml in SQL Server 2008 and I am not getting a result. I have done some online research and came up with the following query. I played around and was able to return the root node, but I need the values from inside and there is an array of call nodes and I need values from it.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://api.myapi.com/resource' as r)
select c.value('@AgentCall','varchar(max)') as value
from mytable cl
outer apply cl.callinfoxml.nodes('//Call') as q(c)
```

Sample XML:

```
<r:ResourceList xmlns:r="http://api.myapi.com/resource" xmlns="http://api.myapi.com/data" totalResults="1">
    <Call id="1123570170003">
        <FromNumber>14062618272</FromNumber>
        <ToNumber>14062618272</ToNumber>
        <State>READY</State>
        <BatchId>12827094003</BatchId>
        <BroadcastId>14633834003</BroadcastId>
        <ContactId>818582749003</ContactId>
        <Inbound>false</Inbound>
        <Created>2016-09-22T06:22:18Z</Created>
        <Modified>2016-09-22T06:22:18Z</Modified>
        <AgentCall>false</AgentCall>
    </Call>
</r:ResourceList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not paying attention to the *default XML namespace* in your document - you need to reference that as well. Try this code:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://api.myapi.com/data', 
                            'http://api.myapi.com/resource' as r)
SELECT 
    c.value('@AgentCall', 'varchar(max)') AS value
FROM
    mytable cl
OUTER APPLY
    cl.callinfoxml.nodes('/r:ResourceList/Call') as q(c)
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked along with changing the select value to `c.value('(AgentCall)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS value`